# Cannot get predicted probabilities from a logistic regression

Tags: r

I made a GLM model with logit link in 2 ways. I want to know the chance to win according to these values, for example, for all combinations of these data. If I use `expand.grid`, I have the same chance to have `win=1` or `win=0` for the same combination of `height`, `weight` and `age`. But if I use `seq`, I don''t have all the combinations.

I also want to be able to predict a probability to win with the following example data: `height=1.89`, `weight=90`, `age=18`. How can I do it?

```
set.seed(1)
mydat <- data.frame(
  win    = as.factor(sample(c(0, 1), 50, replace=TRUE)), 
  weight = runif(50, min=80, max=100),
  height = runif(50, min=1.75, max=1.9),
  age    = runif(50, min=18, max=30)
)
mod1 <- glm(win ~ weight + height + age, data=mydat,       
            family=binomial(link="logit"))

all.x <- expand.grid(height=unique(mydat$height), weight=unique(mydat$weight), 
                     age=unique(mydat$age),win=unique(mydat$win))


plotdat <- data.frame(weight=seq(from=80, to=100, length.out=200),
                      height=seq(from=1.75, to=1.9, length.out=200),
                      age=seq(from=18, to=30, length.out=200))

preddat1 <- predict(mod1, newdata=plotdat, se.fit=TRUE)
preddat2 <- predict(mod1, newdata=all.x, type="response")

dat1 <- data.frame(fit=preddat1$fit,prob=exp(preddat1$fit)/(1+exp(preddat1$fit)), 
            weight=plotdat$weight, height=plotdat$height,
            age=plotdat$age)
dat1 <- dat1[order(dat1[,2]),]

dat2 <- cbind(all.x,preddat2)
dat2 <- dat2[order(dat2[,5]),]
```

Comment: Software-related questions are off-topic on this site (see http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but you can always look for help in one of those: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/793/internet-support-for-statistics-software. As for your problem, simply use this values in newdata argument: `predict(myModel, newdata = data.frame(height=1.89, weight=90, age=18))`.

Comment: "I also want to be able to predict a probability to win with the following example data: height=1.89, weight=90, age=18. How can I do it?" This is a good clear question, and Tim's comment above solves it. Do you have another question? You make several statements about `expand.grid` and `seq`, all of which appear true, and which seem unrelated to the question Tim answered. Is there another question in there? If so, please state it more clearly.